# Why does Airbnb show restricted search results when logged-in?

Tags: bookings, fares, airbnb

I noticed something odd when searching for accommodations on Airbnb.  My initial search turned up some results I was interested in, but when I logged in and re-did the search, those results were no longer there.  I know the places existed and were available, because I ended up booking one of them (by copy-pasting the URL from the initial results).

Has anyone else experienced this kind of thing?  I am hard-pressed to see this as anything other than a deliberate strategic exclusion by Airbnb's search algorithm.  I have heard of online retailers using variable pricing depending on the buyer's demographics.  So are they just trying to wring more money out of me by hiding cheaper places?  What other explanations could there for this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not the helpdesk of Airbnb.

Comment: @chx if I had wanted Airbnb's input I would have contacted them.  I'm looking for independent insight, not spin.  This is an issue highly relevant to travel, is it not?

Comment: One possible explanation is that you first did a broad search, not taking into account dates and the second time you searched based on specific dates. In that case, if an apartment/room is taken, it does not display on the search.

Comment: @nsn yes, I realize "OP is an idiot" is a possible explanation.  It's a reproducible effect, though.  I guess it might just be a glitch/quirk in their code.

Comment: Many of the questions here could have been answered by some company's help desk. What's so special about this one?

Comment: @McGarnagle, did you clear your cookies between searches?

Comment: If he did that he'd lose his login ;)

Comment: @Gayot actually I used a different computer / different browser.

Comment: @Jarnbjo I'm not meaning to ask "why isn't Airbnb working", but rather "do booking agents game their search results".  It is not a question for customer service, but for someone independent with knowledge of industry practices.