# Multiple Airbnb accounts for one stay

Tags: online-resources, bookings, airbnb, reviews

So I've got a few questions regarding a trip I'm on. I'm travelling with a friend of mine, she has her own Airbnb account.

Two situations:

**Prague**
I made the booking on my Airbnb account, but we both stayed in the same place.

**Vienna**
My friend made the booking earlier, but for various reasons, she decided to stay in Prague. Both the host and me were okay with just me going, and I had a wonderful time.

Questions:

1. The review left by my Prague host was for me only. Is there a way my friend could get a review by my Prague host?
2. The Vienna host was amazing, and I'd like to leave her a great review, and more importantly, my Airbnb account is pretty new so I'd love to get a review in return from her. But her review request is connected to my friend, not me. Is there a way my Vienna host and I can exchange reviews?

Comment: So you want a review for someone that didn't use the host's Airbnb? Why? That is a bit dishonest and I kind of hope the host doesn't give you a false review.

Comment: @JonathanReez Airbnb is most certainly a travel topic and we have plenty of questions about it.  Also, why would you answer a question you want to close...?

Comment: @insidesin The friend *did* stay at the Prague Airbnb property, it's just that the booking was under Ash's name and not hers.

Comment: @jpatokal this question was closed as well: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46188/why-does-airbnb-show-restricted-search-results-when-logged-in, so I assumed this one is off-topic.

Comment: @jpatokal close vote retracted

Comment: That question was about what appears to be a bug on the Airbnb site.  This one is not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Go to https://www.airbnb.com/users/references
2. Add your host's email address
3. Click on 'Send request emails'
4. Your host can now write you a reference.
5. Have the host do the same in reverse to leave a review for your friend

[image]

Alternatively you can add them on Facebook and click on the 'Request' button in the *AirBnb Friends* section.